# how add debounce to useSelector on react-redux?

Tags: reactjs, redux

useSelector can listen redux state change; if listen a big array, it can trigger react component rerender so many times. how to optimize it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can add debounce to useSelector:

```
import { useEffect, useRef, useState } from 'react';
import { useSelector } from 'react-redux';

type EqualFn<T> = (before: T, after: T) => boolean;
export function useDebounceSelector<T extends (...args: any) => any>(
    fn: T,
    equalFn?: EqualFn<ReturnType<T>>,
    time = 300,
): ReturnType<T> {
    const [_, setSate] = useState();
    const refData = useRef<any>();
    const refTimeout = useRef<any>();

    useSelector((state: any) => {
        const now_state = fn(state);
        if (now_state === refData.current) {
            return;
        }
        if (equalFn?.(refData.current, now_state)) {
            return;
        }
        refData.current = now_state;
        clearTimeout(refTimeout.current);
        refTimeout.current = setTimeout(() => {
            setSate(refData.current);
        }, time);

        return;
    });

    useEffect(() => {
        return () => clearTimeout(refTimeout.current);
    }, []);

    return refData.current;
}
```

Comment: This works but doesn't prevent useSelector callback function being called on every state change

Comment: it cant, but it can prevent rerender where you use useDebounceSelector.